# Como fazer três botões funcionarem como radio botão?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como fazer três botões funcionarem como "rádio botão".

Ao clicar no botão ele troca de cor e executa comando, ao clicar em outro botão muda de cor e outro volta normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou lhe dar um simples exemplo de uso. Lembre-se que o código abaixo é apenas uma demonstração.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.first); // é apenas um exemplo!
        // ... resto do código

        // Primeiramente, vamos inserir um OnClickListener em nossos três botões.
        findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(bHandler); // Click Listener do Primeiro Botão!
        findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(bHandler); // Listener do segundo
        findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(bHandler); // Listener do terceiro
    }

    View.OnClickListener bHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essa é toda a base que você vai precisar. Agora, você só precisa inserir as ações em cada botão, e ainda verificar se um botão já está selecionado. Use uma variável booleana.

Caso ainda tenha dúvidas em relação as ações de cada botão, deixe um comentário que eu ajudarei.

Abraços.